# Display all custom post type posts and order them by an optional meta_key

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, sticky-post

I have a custom post type (CPT) called `property`. I have registered a featured property `metabox`for it as explained in this question "[How do I create a featured post within a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/how-do-i-create-a-featured-post-within-a-custom-post-type)". So a featured property has got `meta_key='property_featured'` and `meta_value=on`.

What I would like to do is to display **all** `property` posts, but order them by `meta_key='property_featured'`. So that featured properties will appear first in the list on the first page. Similar behavior as `Sticky Posts` functionality. And all the rest `property` posts will be ordered by date created. Also, I need to make sure that pagination is working correctly - treating all the `property` posts alltogether. I use custom pagination code explained [here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin). (Hope that makes sense).

I have tried to specify arguments for WP_Query. However, if I specify:

```
'meta_key' => 'property_featured',
'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

then **only** `property` posts with that key are displayed as opposite to **all** `property` posts.

If I delete `meta_key` from arguments then the query doesn't know what to sort them by.

How do I display all the `property` posts, making sure that `featured` ones appear first and all other `property` posts order by published date?

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order by meta value or date?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/order-by-meta-value-or-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// query posts
$query_property = query_posts( array( 
     'orderby'    => 'date meta_value' // orderby date AND meta value
) );

// First loop
$query_feat = $query_string.'&meta_value=on&meta_key=property_featured';
// Offset for second loop
$query_all = $query_string.'&offset=3&meta_key=property_featured';

// First loop
if ( $query_feat->have_posts() : while ( $query_feat->have_posts() ) : # etc....
    // do stuff
endif;

// Second loop
if ( $query_all->have_posts() : while ( $query_all->have_posts() ) : # etc....
    // do stuff
endif;
?>
```

Comment: it's a 'basic' approach - you should anyway safe another value for that meta key (ex. "off") on save_post and query the second posts by this value.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You're right I ended up saving `property_featured` meta key with the default value of "off", otherwise they weren't even considered by SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to do her is a little too complex. Essentially you want two (meta and date) sort orders applied. Also I think that order by meta value will not work for posts that don't have that value at all.

Stickes is accurate comparison, but note that they are not handled by SQL request, but by completely separate code - they are re-ordered, fetched and applied to results of already completed query.

Unless you want to fork and rewrite stickes logic I think the easiest way would be to move your featured posts to separate loop.