# need some assistance with the checkboxes (selecting/deselecting featured posts)

Tags: post-meta

I am working on a project which has a functionality of "featured_posts" based on this [discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/how-do-i-create-a-featured-post-within-a-custom-post-type). I have created a table which lists all the posts. I have a checkbox in each row which upon click submits the for through javascript. when the box is checked, it updates everything and marks the post as featured.
As a test, i disabled all the featured posts. Upon unchecking the last checkbox, i got

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied

warning. My code is

```
foreach( $_POST['list_id'] as $listID ) {
    if( update_post_meta( $listID, '_property_featured', 'true' ) ) {
        $featureMessage = "Selected listings have been marked as featured successfully.";
    }
    else $featureError = "An error occurred. Please try again.";
}
```

list_id refers to the post_id and was in the value attribute of checkbox. I know when the last checkbox was unchecked, i had to face this warning. Question is how can I track unchecking of checkbox as it is not included in the POST data of the form.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a general PHP warning, you're supplying an incorrect argument in a `foreach` loop.

`$_POST['list_id']` is expected to be an array or any other (iteratable object), when no checkboxes are checked I assume `$_POST['list_id']` is completely undefined.

```
$_POST['list_id'] = isset( $_POST['list_id'] ) ? (array) $_POST['list_id'] : array();
```

Adding this before you iterate over everything should help you get rid of the warning altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Never assume anything about `$_POST`. It is user input and could contain anything. First check if `$_POST['list_id']` exists, using `isset()` or `empty()`. Then make sure it is an array. You may simply cast it to an array if you wish. Finally, make sure the array values are actually absolute integers.

```
$ids = (isset($_POST['list_id'])) ? array_map('absint', (array) $_POST['list_id']) : array();
```

All post IDs not found in the submitted list should be unfeatured.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. What i want is "track a checkbox click on deselect event" as an unchecked checkbox is not submitted on form submit.